# The stone in front of our Lord's Tomb

Tags: kjv

Did the stone in front of the tomb roll away or as in Greek terms it was Sizmos or fly away, from the front of the tomb?

Comment: Hi, welcome. I don't know if this question is really related to Christianity. There is a better site for questions related to Greek and Hebrew. Visit this site - http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for asking this. My first reaction was that I did not remember that it was explicitly mentioned who moved it. And I turned to Matthew *last* (having prepared a *"we don't know"* answer). So, I have learnt something today.

Comment: Just curious, Why would it matter if the stone rolled or flew?

Comment: @Rick That is why I suggested Hermeneutics.SE.

Answer (score 6):

An Angel moved it. [Matthew 28:2](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+28:2&version=NIVUK) states:

> There was a violent earthquake, for **an angel of the Lord** came down from heaven and, going to the tomb, **rolled back the stone** and sat on it.

<sub>Footnote: the other Gospels ([Mark](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%2016:4&version=NIVUK), [Luke](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2024:2&version=NIVUK) and [John](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2020:1&version=NIVUK)) only mention that the stone was moved, but not by whom.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Matthew 28:2 uses the word απεκυλισεν (*apekulisen*, rolls away).
Mark 16:4 uses the word αποκεκυλισται (*apokekulistai*, has been rolled away).
Luke 24:2 uses the word αποκεκυλισμενον (*apokekulismenon*, having been rolled away).
John 20:1 uses the word ηρμενον (*ermenon*, having been lifted/taken away).

No mention of flying, and the word "lifted" only indicates that the stone was taken from one place and put in another.

Reference: [Greek Interlinear Bible](http://www.scripture4all.org/OnlineInterlinear/Greek_Index.htm)